# Should I iterate over hibernate collections to find an entity, or use criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the convention for this? Say for example I have the following, where an item bid can only be a bid on one item:

```
public class Item {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="item", nullable="false"
    Set<ItemBid> itemBids = new HashSet<ItemBid>()
}
```

If I am given the name of the item bidder (which is stored in ItemBid) should I A) Load the club using a club dao and iterate over over the collection of it's itemBids until I find the one with the name I want, or B ) Create an ItemBid dao where the club and item bid name are used in criteria or HQL.

I would presume that B) would be the most efficient with very large collections, so would this be standard for retrieving very specific items from large collections?  If so, can I have a general guideline as to what reasons I should be using the collections, and what time I should be using DAO's / Criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely query bids directly. Here are the guidelines:

- If you are searching for a specific bid, use query
- If you need a subset of bids, use query
- If you want to display all the bids for a given item - it depends. If the number of bids is reasonably small, fetch an item and use collection. Otherwise - query directly.

Of course from OO perspective you should always use a collection (preferably having `findBy*()` methods in `Item` accessing bids collection internally) - which is also more convenient. However if the number of bids per item is significant, the cost of (even lazy-) loading will be significant and you will soon run out of memory. This approach is also very wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should be asking yourself this question much sooner: by the time you were doing the mapping. Mapping for ORM should be an intellectual work, not a matter of copying all the foreign keys onto attributes on both sides. (if only because of YAGNI, but there are many other good reasons)
2. Chances are, the bid-item mapping would be better as unidirectional (then again, maybe not).
3. In many cases we find that certain entities are strongly associated with an almost fixed number of some other entities (they would probably be called "aggregates" in DDD parlance). For example invoices and invoice items. Or a person and a list of his hobbies. Or a post and a set of tags for this post. We do not expect that the number of items in a given invoice will grow over time, nor will the number of tags. So they are all good places to map a @OneToMany. On the other hand, the number of invoices for each client will be growing - so we would just map an unidirectional @ManyToOne from client an invoice - and query.
4. Repositories (daos, whatever) that do queries are perfectly good OO (nothing wrong with a query; it is just an object describing your requirements in a storage-neutral way); using finders in entities - not so. From practical point of view it binds your entities to data access layer (DAOs or even JPA classes), and this will make them unusable in many use cases (GWT) or tricky to use when detached (you will have to guess which methods work outside session). From the philosophical point of view - it violates the single responsibility principle and changes your JPA entities into a sort of active record wannabe.

So, my answer would be:

- if you need a single bid, query directly,
- if you want to display all the bids for a given item - fetch an item and use the collection. This does not depend on the number of bids per item, as the query performed by JPA will be identical as a query you might perform yourself. If this approach needs tuning (like in a case where you need to fetch a lot of items and want to avoid the "N + 1 selects problem") then there is plenty of ways (join fetch, eager fetching, hints) to make it right, without changing the part of the code that uses getBids().

The simplest way to think about it is: if you think that some collection will never be displayed with paging (like tags on post, items on invoice, hobbies on person), map it with @OneToMany and access as a collection.